# Are there any apps that can download lyrics for all the music files in a folder?

Tags: downloads, lyrics

I don't want the app to be launching any existing music player and displaying lyrics I just want the lyrics files to be downloaded.I also want the lyrics files to be of .lrc extension and currently I'm using ubuntu 14.10.
Please help.

Comment: Do you know that the lyrics are available for the music files, in lrc or another format? Do you know where?

Comment: yes. .lrc is the usual format for lyrics files. I have a mobile player which supports .lrc files.so I can also use these files in my mobile.

Answer (score 1):

The programs that work with lyrics and other music metadata can make use of a library named `libglyr`.
There is a program providing a command line interface to it's features, `glyrc`. I could not see which lyrics file formats are used in the man page, but it seems to be worth a try.
(Possibly it is somethinig like the standard minimal UI for `libglyr` library development - then, it may be cryptic, but very complete.)

From [`man glyrc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/glyrc.1.html):

```
 NAME

        glyrc - search engine for music-related metadata

 USAGE

               glyrc GETTER [options]
        where GETTER must be one of:
        · cover
        · lyrics
        · artistphoto
        · artistbio
        · similarartists
        · similarsongs
        · albumreview
        · albumlist
        · tags
        [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best choice from the commandline is certainly glyrc. Below is an example of typical usage for downloading and writing a lyric file:

```
glyrc lyrics --artist "Pink Floyd" \
             --album "Dark Side of the Moon" \
             --title "Money" \
             --write "money.lrc"
```

As far as I know glyrc requires the individual songname or title to download in this way so some scripting will be required to download a *set* of lyrics...